# Fetching operations from Ncache server is taking time than previously

Tags: caching, host, application-cache, ncache

In my office, we have a server that has Ncache installed for storing and retrieving data and our applications are also hosted there.
There was an issue where application was getting timed out. In depth, i found that getting cache method from Ncache is taking 8-9 seconds, which was previously taking 0.5 seconds. The application isn't changed recently and it was working fine previously. All of a sudden this issue has occurred. Some one told me that there was an issue where all of a sudden all clustered cache were deleted from ncache manager and we resolved it by setting basic values from tutorial available online. But this issue seems to be never getting solved. Can anyone through some light on it that we can do to overcome this time out issue?

Comment: Do you have a cluster setup? If so what is the connection status? Connected, partially connected e.t.c

Comment: i have set up cluster cache. Connection status is fully connected.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like some application/environment related issue where a working application is now showing slow fetch time while it was working fine previously. Also, if your console app is getting results in less than a second then it again shows that issue is not from NCache server end but isolated to the application.

I will suggest to review what has been changed in the application to start off. You can also profile your application on which calls are taking more time now. NCache client side windows performance counters can also be reviewed to rule out if it is slow because of NCache or due to some application related issue.

Moreover, caching an object which is huge in size is generally not recommended.  You should always break your bigger objects to smaller objects and then cache them. This will reduce network and storage overhead for your application. If you have to use bigger object then consider using compression.

NCache default settings are already tuned for optimum performance and should not slow things down.  You should check firewall between client and NCache server to rule out any environmental issues.